# Customtkinter Combobox

Tags: pycharm, fullscreen, customtkinter

I have no issue with the code exept that when i click on the drop down bar it opens from top of screen to bottom of screen , is there any way to limit this displayed data in the dropdown menu to like 10-20 items and just scrolls through them ? Here is my code that works : customtkinter i use in pycharm.

date_dropdown = ctk.CTkComboBox(master=popup, values=dates_list, state="readonly")
date_dropdown.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

Thank you for your help.

I have tried columnspan, height did not work.